# How to use a fabric 1.4 wallet with fabric node sdk 2.x

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have an existing Hyperledger Fabric network v1.4 and I am trying to connect to the network using Fabric node SDK 2.2.x. Every time I try to connect I get an error

```
Error : Pem Encoded certificate is required
```

The requirement that I have is that the network is v1.4 and the application code got reworked in SDK 2.2.x
due to the better event listener support but the existing wallet do not allow us to connect to the network. Is there a way we can connect with the already existing wallet to the network .

Also we cannot update the network as of now .

I am a newbie here so I might have missed something that I am more than willing to answer when someone points it out.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation page has details of wallet changes and a link to an npm package that can be used to either use a v1.4 wallet directly with the v2.x SDK, or convert a v1.4 format wallet to a v2.x format wallet:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-migration.html